# Vue form submit doesn't work if the form has a hidden field

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js, vuetify.js

My application's login form works similar to Google Account login - first the user enters their email address and then either they are redirected to their SSO or are shown a password field.

In the Chromium documentation, Google calls this an "Email First Sign-in Flow", and [recommends the following structure](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/form-styles-that-chromium-understands) to enable password managers to understand the form:

> Collect the email:
>
> ```html
> <form id="login" action="login.php" method="post"> 
>   <input type="text" autocomplete="username">
>   <input type="submit" value="Sign In!">
> </form>
> ```
>
> Then collect the password, but include the email as the value of a hidden form field:
>
> ```html
> <style>
> #emailfield {
>   display: none;
> }
> </style>
> <form id="login" action="login.php" method="post">
>   <input id="emailfield" type="text" value="me@example.test" autocomplete="username">  
>   <input type="password" autocomplete="current-password">
>   <input type="submit" value="Sign In!">
> </form>
> ```

Here is how I implemented this in Vue (with Vuetify):

```
<template>
    <v-app id="sm-login">
        <v-container class="fill-height" fluid>
            <v-card class="mx-auto px-10 pb-9" width="450px" :loading="loading">
                <v-card-title class="justify-center pt-12">My App</v-card-title>
                <v-card-subtitle class="text-center py-6 headline">Log In</v-card-subtitle>
                <v-card-text class="text-center">
                    <v-form ref="form1" v-if="showForm === 1" @submit.prevent="lookupEmail">
                        <v-text-field
                            autocomplete="username"
                            label="Email"
                            v-model.trim="email"
                            name="email"
                            outlined
                            ref="email"
                            required
                            type="email"
                            :error-messages="errorMessage"
                            :rules="[rules.required, rules.email]" />
                    </v-form>
                    <v-form ref="form2" v-if="showForm === 2" @submit.prevent="login">
                        <input style="display:none" name="email" type="email" v-model="email" readonly autocomplete="username" />
                        <v-chip outlined class="mb-6" close @click:close="showForm = 1"><v-avatar left><v-icon>mdi-account-circle</v-icon></v-avatar> {{email}}</v-chip>
                        <v-text-field
                            label="Password"
                            v-model="password"
                            name="password"
                            outlined
                            ref="password"
                            required
                            spellcheck="false"
                            :append-icon="showPassword ? 'mdi-eye' : 'mdi-eye-off'"
                            :autocomplete="showPassword ? 'off' : 'current-password'"
                            :error-messages="errorMessage"
                            :type="showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'"
                            @click:append="showPassword = !showPassword"
                             />
                    </v-form>
                </v-card-text>
                <v-card-actions>
                    <v-spacer />
                    <v-btn color="primary" @click="clickButton">{{nextButton}}</v-btn>
                </v-card-actions>
            </v-card>
        </v-container>
    </v-app>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            loading: false,
            email: '',
            password: '',
            errorMessage: '',
            showForm: 1,
            showPassword: false,
            rules: {
                required: value => !!value || Lang.get('validation-short.email'),
                email: value => {
                    const pattern = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
                    return pattern.test(value) || Lang.get('validation-short.email')
                },
            },
        };
    },
    computed: {
        nextButton() {
            switch (this.showForm) {
            case 1:
                return Lang.get('auth.next');
            case 2:
                return Lang.get('auth.log-in');
            }
        },
    },
    methods: {
        lookupEmail() {
            if (this.$refs.form1.validate()) {
                // The email lookup is done here, and either
                // redirected to SSO or set `this.showForm = 2`
            }
        },
        login() {
            if (this.$refs.form2.validate()) {
                // Login is done here
            }
        },
        clickButton() {
            switch (this.showForm) {
                case 1: return this.lookupEmail();
                case 2: return this.login();
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the first form (with the Email field in focus) works properly - it calls the `lookupEmail` function. However, pressing it on the second form (with the Password field in focus) does nothing. When I comment out the hidden Email field in the second form, the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key submits the form as expected (but the password manager does not have the email address populated).

When I look in the Vue DevTools extension "Events" tab, I see that the Email field triggers two events, `keydown` on the `<VTextField>` and `submit` on the `<VForm>`. However, the Password field only triggers the `keydown` event on the `<VTextField>` but the `submit` event does not appear in the DevTools.

Why does the hidden field cause the form to stop catching `submit` events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow this seems to be related to [using `v-model` on hidden fields](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/1194).

Changing the code from:

```html
<input style="display:none" name="email" type="email" v-model="email" readonly autocomplete="username" />
```

to:

```html
<input name="email" type="hidden" :value="email" autocomplete="username" />
```

appears to fix the issue.

Note that both changes seem to be required: switching from `display: none` to `type="hidden"` and from `v-model=` to `:value=`